# I want to create a method to check if the Date is in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format in apex

Tags: regex, datetime, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

This is the snippet I want to be the structure like this:

```
public static boolean validateDateFormat(String date1) {
  if(date1.format('mm/dd/yyyy')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it is by using regex:

```
public static boolean validateDateFormat(String date1){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}'); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date1);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Note that `\d` specifies digit and the number in `{}` after it specifies the quantity e.g. `\d{2}` specifies 2 digits.